# Showing only a few elements, others can navigate using the arrows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good moorning.
I have got a variable $awards = array which contents some data from database from specific users. This variable extracts a set of awards to result set of users.

```
<div>
  <span class="zoom-gallery" n:foreach="$awards as $award" n:if="$award['user_id'] == $solver['id']">
    <a href="{$basePath}{$award['link']}">
      <img src="{$basePath}{$award['preview']}"/>
    </a> 
  </span>
</div>
```

However, some users have so much awards -> I would like to show first 4 awards between two arrows allowing going through the other.

Example: arrow_prev AWARD1 AWARD2 AWARD3 AWARD4 arrow_next

Could you help me how to do it? I know it's solvable through javascript but I dont know javascrip much (beginner). Or - does exist some plugin? Thank you